# Blank PHP Screen -- Updating Database with a Form

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to this so please bear with me. I'm trying to make a page where a logged in user can update their row of information in the database. I've been sitting here for hours trying to figure this out, so maybe someone can help shed some light on this. Right now I'm even getting a blank white page and can't figure out why.

```
   <?php
require_once('auth.php');
require_once('config.php');

$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$conn) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . "'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'] = $member['email'];
        session_write_close();
        //header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}

    ?>
```

And then I'm trying to display the result of the query in my form I have created as the default value already in the box. From what I can tell it should be something like this?

```
    <input name="fname" type="text" class="textfield" id="fname" value="<?php echo $member['member_id'] ?>"/>
```

From there I want to pass the new data along so I can write the update sql statement.

Or if you have some sort of resource that can help explain it to me in a simple manner, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You'll need to enable `display_errors`. At the top of your script, before the includes, do `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` You likely have some fatal error that you aren't seeing the result of.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I get worried when I see PHP code not using [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. I hope you are sanitizing `$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']` in code that hasn't been pasted here. If not, please consider re-writing the code to use PDO Prepared Statements rather than trying to sanitize your variables.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am aware of the issue. I'm just trying to get it working first, and then I was going to go back and mend that part.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `display_errors` call when you put this into production, but always use it in development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `exit()` after a successful query. If you proceed to display results, your script will already have terminated.

```
    $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['lastname'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'] = $member['email'];
    //header("location: index.php");
    // Don't call exit()!
    // Remove this!
    exit();
```

Comment: @devkitt If you're satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the gray checkmark. And welcome to Stack Overflow.